# Can I edit Bitcoin Core's config file with a text editor?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat

Must changes to bitcoin.conf only be made using the GUI settings options?

Or can I edit the file with a text editor such as Notepad?

Comment: Again, find someone to help you write questions. This is incomprehensible.

Comment: @Pieter: I replaced it with something that is either what the author meant or something completely different but less unintelligible.  The jury is out on whether this will act as an example for OP or merely encourage further incomprehensible postings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can edit the config file with a plain-text editor. However using the GUI is less likely to cause the file to contain invalid data that will cause alarming or potentially impoverishing problems.

If there are reasons to not use the GUI to change the configuration, using the [command line options](https://gist.github.com/donpdonp/4997294) may be safer than editing the config file.